# Erro para instalar aplicação VB.NET no Windows Server

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação no meu notebook com Win7 64 bits com VS2005 e VB Form. Fiz uma instalação em um Windows Server 32. Não uso internet e quando instalo a aplicação, ela roda perfeitamente até o ponto onde tento gerar um relatório com o *Crystal Reports* exatamente no ponto:

```vb
Dim rptXml As New ReportDocument()
```

Como não uso internet, ou seja, Asp.Net, não preciso do IIS instalado. Como faço para corrigir este problema?

Já instalei o *Crystal Reports* e o .Net 2.0, tudo para 32 bits e nada de funcionar. No meu notebook, funciona perfeitamente.

O erro retornado pelo *Crystal Reports* é esse:

> :System.TypeInitializationException: O inicializador de tipo de 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument' acionou uma exceção. ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Falha na recuperação de factory de classes COM do componente com CLSID {11BD5260-15B6-412D-80DB-12BB60B8FE50} devido ao seguinte erro: 80070005. em CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument..cctor()

Comment: NÃO POSTE TEXTO USANDO TUDO EM MAIÚSCULAS!!! Pois este comportamento tende a irritar os demais usuários e deixa o texto difícil de ser lido. O resultado disso será que você vai receber votos negativos e nenhuma ajuda. Já editei a sua pergunta para deixá-la com o formato de texto normal, portanto agora é só esperar que alguém que saiba como respondê-la (eu não sei) venha lhe ajudar ou talvez pedir maiores esclarecimentos sobre a sua pergunta.

Comment: Aliás, o seu notebook é tudo 32 bits também ou é 64? A versão do sistema operacional, do Crystal Reports e do .Net no seu notebook é a mesma que está no servidor?

Comment: Eu realmente não entendi qual o erro. Você só fala que sem internet funciona e que no notebook funciona, mas não explica o que ocorre quando não funciona, se da alguma mensagem de erro, entende?

Comment: desculpe o comportamento, mas sou novo neste forum, o meu note é 64bit e o servidor é 32bit, já alterei no VS2005 para deploy coim x86. e o erro que esta retornando neste ponto do programa é :System.TypeInitializationException: O inicializador de tipo de 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument' acionou uma exceção. ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Falha na recuperação de factory de classes COM do componente com CLSID {11BD5260-15B6-412D-80DB-12BB60B8FE50} devido ao seguinte erro: 80070005.
   em CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument..cctor()

Comment: O aplicativo roda com o usuário padrão do IIS? Como está configurado (IIS ou Web.config) o tipo de autenticação e como estão as permissões do usuário que roda o trecho do código do report?

Comment: o aplicativo é windows form, desenv. com vs2005 form, não precisa do IIS, ele gera um .exe

Answer (score 0):

Acho que o seu problema deve ser que no seu servidor, o *Crystal Reports* não tem todas as permissões para leitura e escritas de arquivos de que ele precisa em sua pasta de trabalho ou não está configurado para executar como um serviço. O fato de aparecer o texto `System.UnauthorizedAccessException` na sua mensagem de erro é um forte indicativo disso.

Outra possível causa, mas menos provável, é a de você ter mais do que uma versão do *Crystal Reports* instalada no servidor.

Cheguei a essa conclusão a partir [deste link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1767121.aspx?Crystal+Report+Error+), no qual uma pessoa que estava tendo um problema que me parece ser bem parecido com o seu:

> Error Message:Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {11BD5260-15B6-412D-80DB-12BB60B8FE50} failed due to the following error: 8007007e.
>   Stack Trace:   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument..cctor()

Bem, aqui está a solução para o problema, conforme lá se encontra, retirando algumas partes claramente irrelevantes:

> It is quite normal if you are experiencing issues when deploying Crystal Report 2010 on a server. Based on the error message you experienced,  it seems that you have not properly setup/configured your Crystal Report on the PC/server:
>
> 1. If you see this error message: "Type 'CrystalDecisions.Shared.CrystalReportsException' in assembly 'CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' is not marked as serializable", this is due to the fact that your PC is unable to find the right Crystal Report version on your PC. Please try to UNINSTALL any previous Crystal Report version that you have on your system and then, please install Crystal Report for VS 2010 there. You can go to http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_redist_install_64bit_13_0_1.zip (for 64 bit machine) OR http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_redist_install_32bit_13_0_1.zip (for 32 bit machine) OR http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_13_0_1.exe (FULL package)
> 2. Once you have the CR installed on your system, please make sure you set your Crystal Report to operate on LOCAL SERVICE permission. Please check your application pool and make sure it runs under this permission
> 3. Please make sure the FULL TRUST read and write permission is set on your working folder
> 4. Please make sure you copy the CR aspnet_client folder to your working folder
>
> Once you have done all the steps above, your crystal report 2010 should work fine.
>
> P.S: Please always make sure you have one Crystal Report version running on your own server. If you have multiple different CR version, your report will not work!

Traduzindo para o português:

> É um tanto normal que você esteja experimentando problemas ao implantar o Crystal Report 2010 em um servidor. Baseado na mensagem de erro que você está experimentando, parece que você não configurou adequadamente o seu Crystal Report no seu PC/Servidor:
>
> 1. Se você está vendo esta mensagem de erro: "Type 'CrystalDecisions.Shared.CrystalReportsException' in assembly 'CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' is not marked as serializable", isto é devido ao fato de que o seu PC não pôde encontrar a versão correta do Crystal Report para o seu PC. Por favor tente DESINSTALAR qualquer versão anterior do Crystal Report que você tenha em seu sistema e então, por favor instale Crystal Report para VS 2010 lá. Você pode ir para http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_redist_install_64bit_13_0_1.zip (para uma máquina de 64 bits) OU http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_redist_install_32bit_13_0_1.zip (para uma máquina de 32 bits) OU http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_13_0_1.exe (pacote completo)
> 2. Uma vez que você tenha o CR instalado em seu sistema, por favor certifique-se que você configure o seu Crystal Report para operar com permissão LOCAL SERVICE. Por favor verifique seu conjunto de aplicações e crtifique-se que ele roda sob esta permissão
> 3. Por favor certifique-se que a permissão de CONTROLE TOTAL de leitura e escrita está definida para a sua pasta de trabalho
> 4. Por favor certifique-se de copiar a pasta aspnet_client do CR para a sua pasta de trabalho
>
> Uma vez que você tenha concluído todos os passos acima, o seu crystal report 2010 deve funcionar bem.
>
> P.S: Por favor sempre certifique-se de que você tem apenas uma versão do Crystal Report rodando em seu servidor. Se você tiver múltplas versões diferentes do CR, seu relatório não vai funcionar!

Comment: Boa Tarde Victor, ajustei cfe o post, mas deu o um novo erro no mesmo ponto do programa, System.TypeInitializationException: O inicializador de tipo de 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument' acionou uma exceção. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Falha na recuperação de factory de classes COM do componente com CLSID {11BD5260-15B6-412D-80DB-12BB60B8FE50} devido ao seguinte erro: 80040154.

Comment: Boa Tarde; então, efetuei todos os passos acima, e mesmo assim continua apresentando o mesmo erro. Já não sei em que ponto mexer, ou se de repente é o próprio servidor que esteja faltando algo, lembrando que não tenho o IIS instalado, pois a aplicação VB é desktop feita no vs 2005.

Comment: Boa Noite Pessoal; obrigado pelas dicas, foi de grande ajuda, acabei por desinstalar tudo e reinstalar cfe as dicas acima, e recompilei a aplicacao exportando juntos somente os pre-requisitos do .net e o reportviewer e assim funcionou, mostrou o relatorio cfe previsto.